# Possible to have a web page only viewable by people on the same network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, file-upload

I'd like to do a node.js express application that can host files, the catch is that only people on the same network can view that file.

For example on this site it is completely public, it has a domain name. On the site I can host a text file.  People who go to this site outside of my current network, cannot view the file, but people on the current network can.

Is this possible? If so what do I need to research? I'd like to keep the barrier to entry super low, as no accounts or auth.

Comment: If your current network is defined as the network within your office environment, and your file and folder structures are not secret, simply provide links to the files in the form `\\server\filename`.  They will be inaccessible to anyone outside the firewall.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - what about in non-Windows/non-Samba environments?

Comment: So two links then.  I agree that it's clumsy, but it has the virtue of being expedient.

Comment: I am sorry, let me clarify, anyone would be able to post files to a server that would only be accessible to their network. So people can post from many different networks. If a friend where to post from his home, I would not be able to view it unless I was on his network.  But everyone on his network would be able to view it.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're talking about a bona fide security system of some sort.  Logins, authentication, groups, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the server to the internal-network ip.

Eg:

```
app.listen(8080, '192.168.0.10');
```

And only computers within the same network will be able to access it, no auth required, nothing special. But beware, if you have a local proxy/router which forwards all packets to that (local) IP, then every request forwarded will work (will be treated as local).